# How do you change the data Color of a line chart in Power BI based on Slicer Selection

Tags: switch-statement, powerbi, linechart, slicers

I have a table of selections that has no relationship and only serves to be a selector for a filter:

[image]

I then have this feed a slicer on my page so that when the user selectes a value, the following measure will evaluate (works great):

```
Metric Toggle = SWITCH(TRUE(),
SELECTEDVALUE(Metrics[Metric]) = "Current Ratio", MAX('FinancialData'[CurrentRatio])
,SELECTEDVALUE(Metrics[Metric]) = "Debt to Tangible Net Worth", MAX('FinancialData'[DebtToTNW])
,SELECTEDVALUE(Metrics[Metric]) = "Gross Sales", MAX('FinancialData'[GrossSales])
,SELECTEDVALUE(Metrics[Metric]) = "NetSales", MAX('FinancialData'[NetSales])
,SELECTEDVALUE(Metrics[Metric]) = "Current Portion of Long Term Debt", MAX('FinancialData'[CPLTD])
,SELECTEDVALUE(Metrics[Metric]) = "EBITDA", MAX('FinancialData'[EBITDA])
,0)
```

This measure drives a line chart. Is it possible to conditionally format the data line color on the chart for each selection? i.e If user selected "EBITDA", then line colour = Blue, If User Selected "Current Ratio", then Line Color = Red... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deselect your Slicer value as below

[image]

Now add **Metric** to the **Line Chart's Legend** property and go to the Chart's property **Data Color** and you will find a list like below-

[image]

Now, select your specific colors for specific **Metric** value. Once you complete all the above setup, you will get your expected color for Line based on the Slicer selection.

Comment: Thanks so much. I guess the other lesson here is "don't make things too complicated", which can be easy to do in PBI.

Comment: nice to see it helped :)